# subtree merge claims already up-to-date

Tags: git, git-subtree

I haven't had much luck pushing/pulling changes from subtrees.  Usually I use the 'git subtree' command to create the subtree and pull changes. When pulling I get lame conflicts to fix (when there really is not conflict) and pushing never works.

So today I am trying a different approach, using subtree merges instead of the git subtree command.  I followed the instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/.

First, I create the remote to the repository I want to use as a subtree:

```
git remote add -f cumulonimbus-machine http://github.com/fschwiet/cumulonimbus-machine
git merge -s ours --no-commit cumulonimbus-machine/old
git merge -s ours --no-commit cumulonimbus-machine/fschwiet
```

The 'old' branch is a parent of the 'fschwiet' branch.  I wanted to base the subree on 'old' initially so I can test pulling changes (pulling the remainder of 'fschwiet').  Anyhow, I create the subtree:

```
git read-tree --prefix=host/ -u cumulonimbus-machine/old
```

This works fine.  All the files are in the hosts folder, and I can see its the older branch as expected.  Then I try to get some updates:

```
git pull -s subtree cumulonimbus-machine fschwiet
```

and I get some disappointing output:

```
From http://github.com/fschwiet/cumulonimbus-machine
 * branch            fschwiet   -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date
```

I expected this last pull would update the host directory to have the latest from the 'fschwiet' branch.  But it hasn't pulled down anything.  I did verify 'old' and 'fschwiet' are not actually the same commit.  I tried pulling some other ways with the same results:

```
git subtree merge --prefix=host cumulonimbus-machine/fschwiet
git merge -X subtree=host cumulonimbus-machine/fschwiet
git subtree pull --prefix=host cumulonimbus-machine 90686ba2d0c31afdc516611064
git subtree pull --prefix=host cumulonimbus-machine master
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in running

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit cumulonimbus-machine/fschwiet
```

before

```
git read-tree --prefix=host/ -u cumulonimbus-machine/old
```

This created a merge commit pulling in the contents of the 'old' branch, but telling the repository it was in sync with the 'fschwiet' branch.

I did learn something valuable after all this though.  It seems some of the merge problems I've had may be resolved if I used

```
git merge -X subtree=host cumulonimbus-machine/fschwiet
```

instead of git merge -s subtree or git subtree merge.  This seems to do a smarter merge algorithm.  In particular, it removed files that were deleted (unlike git subtree merge).